# Excel vba macro to connect to a particular webpage - search and retrieve data

Tags: vba, excel

I have column, say column A containing 1500 rows each having a string (Hexadecimal encodes). What I need is connect to a particular website search paste the string, press on decode, copy the result and paste it back to column B.

Any help would be of great help.  I am new here.

Example:

String in Column A: `5468616e6b732061206c6f7420696e20616476616e6365`

Website to search in: http://encodertool.com/hexadecimal

1. Copy from excel cell and paste in tab (under heading): ENTER AN Hexadecimal CONTENT TO DECODE
2. Then hit DECODE
3. Then Copy from DECODING RESULT
4. Finally paste back in ColumnB in my excel sheet.

Looking forward for an answer.

Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this as an exercise in automating the browser?  Seems like you could more easily do it directly in VBA

From: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/874752-convert-hex-string

```
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print fConvertHexToString( _
             "5468616e6b732061206c6f7420696e20616476616e6365")
End Sub



Public Function fConvertHexToString(strHexString As String) As String
Dim intLenOfString As Integer
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim strBuild As String

'Hex String must have a valid length, and it must be an even length
If Len(strHexString) = 0 Or Len(strHexString) Mod 2 <> 0 Then Exit Function

intLenOfString = Len(strHexString)

For intCounter = 1 To Len(strHexString)
  If intCounter Mod 2 <> 0 Then     'need Hex pairs
    'Retrieve the Value of the Hex Pair, then Convert to a Character,
    'then Append to a Base String
    strBuild = strBuild & Chr$(Val("&H" & Mid$(strHexString, intCounter, 2)))
  End If
Next
fConvertHexToString = strBuild
End Function
```

Comment: @user3752399 : Wow! As suggested by Tim, if its not for accessing the website, you could go for the above answer. +1 for the conversion

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. I have just run a mock test and it works. Give it a try. You can modify the code to your needs. This is a plain code. Code can be enhanced as well. But this does what you ask for

```
       Dim ie As InternetExplorer
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument

        Sub start()

        Dim ran As Range
        Dim cel As Excel.Range

        Set ran = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4") 'Change Your input range here

            For Each cel In ran
                If cel.Value <> Empty Then
                    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium 'open iE
                    ie.navigate ("http://encodertool.com/hexadecimal") 'Navigate to IE
                    ie.Visible = True
                        'Wait untill IE is loaded
                        Do
                        ' Wait till the Browser is loaded
                        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                    Set doc = ie.document
                    doc.getElementById("input_4").innerText = cel.Value ' Enter input value
                    test ' Click button
                    cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = doc.getElementById("output_4").innerText ' save Output value
                End If
                ie.Quit
                Next cel

            End Sub


    'Click the Decode button
    Sub test()

            Set cl_button= doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

            For Each one In cl_button
            If one.getAttribute("onclick") = "ajaxfct('fcts.php','4')" Then
            one.Click
            Exit For
            End If
            Next one

    End Sub
```

Before running the code, add reference to HTML object library & Internet controls. Also change the range of your input. I have set it to A1:A4 . Change to it whatever. Make sure there are no blank cells in the Range. ALso, If you dont want the browser to be displayed set

```
ie.visible = false
```

This is one way of doing it. THere are many simpler and effective ways of doing it

Comment: Thanks a lot Sriram - let me give it a try and get back to you.  Cheers